# AJAX/JQUERY show and hide button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, button

Here is my previous post and thank you to sir @Satpal that I finally got the button working. But now I have another bug.

This is what my goal that will happen to my site:
every I click a certain row (".emp_delete") the .deleteBtn shows up and hides when clicked on another row.

The button doesn't show up after searching. Can someone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#employee_list').delegate( ".emp_delete", 'click', function() {
              var ID=$(this).attr('id'); 
              $("#delete_"+ID).show();
        });

        $('#employee_list').delegate(".deleteBtn", 'click', function(){

            var ID=$(".emp_delete").attr('id');

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            var dataString = 'emp_id='+ID;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('c_employee/delete_employee'); ?>",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
        else
            return false;

        });

        $("#searchText").keypress(function(){   //change to keypress
            var search = $("#searchText").val();
            var dataString = 'search='+search;


            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('c_employee/get_search'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json', 
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#employee_list").empty();

                        $.each(data, function(index, val) {

                            $("#employee_list").append('<tr class="emp_delete" id="'+val.emp_id+'"><td>'+val.emp_id+'</td><td>'+val.last_name+'</td><td>'+val.first_name+
                                '</td><td>'+val.middle_in+'</td>'+
                                '<td><input type="button" value="Resigned Employee" class="deleteBtn" id="delete_"'+val.emp_id+'"></td></tr>');
                        });

                    }
                 });

             });

    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        $(".deleteBtn").hide();

    });
```

Comment: do you mean the button doesnt show when the search results are loaded or when you click on the row?

Comment: you mean you want to hide the delete button when you delete a row ?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of your code

Comment: For this first reading, I can see two problems on the first 6 lines. When you click an employee, you want the corresponding "delete button" to appear, but, you also want all the others to hide. Then, when you write `var ID=$(".emp_delete")` you are mistaken !! `$(".emp_delete)` will retrun an Array !! all element corresponding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using on().

```
$("#employee_list").on("click", "tr.emp_delete", function(){
    $(".deleteBtn").hide();
    $(this).find(".deleteBtn").show();
});
```